# I have a box that appeared and I cannot get rid of it

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I accidently fat fingered my keyboard and a box appeared around my object...I guess it's a bounding box or something but I have no clue how to get it to disappear. When I select all objects in edit mode and move the objects the box doesn't move.  I can't edit, or resize it and if I copy my object to another scene, the stupid box goes along with it. Does anyone know how to turn this thing off?  Help would certainly be much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: consider sharing your file so that others can take a look a it.

Comment: susu, thanks for the response.  I apologize, I didn't see your message.   I do appreciate your willingness to help.  Thank you very much.  Luckily I figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I stumbled on it by accident.  I guess there is a hotkey for it somewhere.  This is a texture space.  In version 2.7x it was a yellow dotted box, but in 2.8 it looks like a bounds box.  I removed the texture space tick from Viewport Display and the box disappeared.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the outliner for the object it looks like a boolean cut so it should be in the outliner or it is a similuation thing like a fluid domain or something check that way and it should work

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for the response.  I only have one item in the outliner.  I've added a picture to the post.  Usually I'm pretty good finding stuff in 2.8 but this one has me stumped.

Comment: Have you inadvertantly checked the 'Bounds' checkbox under the object's Viewport Display properties?

Comment: Thanks John for the response.  Bounds is not selected.  I've added an image to the post that shows the display settings.

Comment: In that case I've no idea I'm afraid! :^(

Comment: Yea it's a tough one.  I've redone the project but kept the file because I am curious if anyone will be able to answer it for me.  I really would like to know what it is and how to get rid of it.  Might forward it to Blender to get their buy in as to what it could be.  Tanks a bunch though!